# Does changing an .exe's file extension to .old make it no longer executable?

Tags: windows, windows-11, file-extension

Some programs leave their old `.exe` files in place when updating.  For instance, `abc1.2.3.exe` is left there when `abc1.2.4.exe` is installed.

It's still useful to have the old file around for easy troubleshooting without transferring files or running executables.  However, it's a security hole as someone can still run the old executable.  If I rename the file to `.old` , will that ensure that a script can't run `abc1.2.3.old` as a program?

I understand that a person or script with appropriate permissions could just name it back, but let's take the example as stated.

Comment: "If I rename the file to .old , will that ensure that a script can't run abc1.2.3.old as a program?" - No; Windows can execute an application with or without a file extension.  The file being an executable has to do with header within the file itself.

Answer (score 2):

Renaming the file to end in .old makes it so that double-clicking on the file within the Windows UI will not execute it, normally, as the .old file type is unlikely to be associated with the systems executable files are associated with in order to, you know, execute.

What it does not do is actually change the nature of the file. It is still, deep down, an executable file, and there are ways to call the file that will execute it, though this renaming may further hamper its behavior depending on how it is programmed.

Regarding your script: that depends on what the script says. If the script is specifically looking for abc123.exe, and you have renamed that file to abc123.old, the script will fail because there is no file with the name it is looking for. But if the script uses another method to identify the file and run it, it may still be able to run.

So, overall, the answer is "it depends".